# Node.js nvm and npm directory structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nvm

today I noticed that I couldn't execute some node.js programs (e.g. weinre) from the shell by typing `$ weinre`. But I had it installed (two versions even) in `~/.npm/weinre/2.0.0-pre-2012-03-02--15-31-31/package/weinre` and in `~/.npm/weinre/2.0.0-pre-H41DGW8S-incubating/package/weinre`. To top it off, I also have a `~/local/node_modules/` path, but there's only socket.io. (I'm on a Mac and `~/local/` is in my path, I use it instead of `/usr/local/`).

So it appears that node modules can be in `~/.nvm/v0.8.1/lib/node_modules`, in `~/.npm` (with version number and "package" subfolder) and in `~/local/node_modules`. So where *should* they go?

I ran `npm install -g weinre` which installed an alias to `~/.nvm/v0.8.1/bin/weinre`. The alias points to `~/.nvm/v0.8.1/lib/node_modules/weinre/weinre`. I still have the other two weinres in the `~/.npm/weinre` path written above.

Something seems to be broken here...can someone please explain or help to fix it? :(

Answer (score 1):

(nvm maintainer here)

Everything in `~/.npm` is npm's cache; you shouldn't be looking in there or concerned with it at all :-)

Your global node modules will be in `npm root -g`. `~/.nvm/v0.8.1/lib/node_modules` is that path for the nvm-managed node version 0.8.1; `~/local/node_modules` is probably that path for your system node.